Remap keyboard keys
I want to switch Caps Lock and Shift keys as Shift seems to have a hardware issue.
I followed the instructions in here. The keycodes of the two keys are 50 and 65 so I switched their functions, saved the file and run

xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap~

however effect didn't take place.

I know how to do it with xbindkeys and xdotool.
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xdotool

Run xbindkeys -d and it will create the default ~/.xbindkeysrc
Add the following:
`# Caps Lock as Shift
"xdotool key shift"
  Caps_Lock

Then, run xbindkeys -p to poll the new entry.
